# Javascript TypeError: result of expression is not an object

Tags: javascript

This should be real simple... But it ain't... >.<

```
var x = document.getElementById('x');
function snooze()
{
x.style.height = '10px';
}
```

Upon execution, the error I get is:

`TypeError: Result of expression 'x' [null] is not an object.`

Edit: Heads up, it works when I put the var declaration inside the function. I don't understand... :-(

```
function snooze()
{
var x = document.getElementById('x');
x.style.height = '10px';
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Either:

1. There is no element on the page with `id="x"`.
2. The code is running before the document is loaded.

If an element with `id="x"` exists, try:

```
window.onload = function () {
    // your code in here
};
```

Comment: O.. Om... Omg... OQWUGOUB!
I can't believe that calling the script at the end of the page didn't occur to me before... You sir (or ma'am, whichever you prefer), deserve a medal...

Comment: `window.onload` happens very, very late in the page load cycle (after *all* external resources like images and such load). *Sometimes* that's what you want, but rarely. To run it earlier, just put the `script` element at the very end of the `body` element. More [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) and [here](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41).

Comment: He/she already has 41 medals here! http://stackoverflow.com/users/405143/box9?tab=stats

Comment: @Kooilnc - Well, another one wouldn't hurt... :-)